# Lowenheim numbers for ordinary language quantifiers

Tags: logic, model-theory, quantifiers

I am interested in the Lowenheim numbers associated with quantifiers that are prevalent in ordinary language use, such as "more" and "most".

Definition: The *Lowenheim number* of L, $\ell$(L),  is the least cardinal $\mu$ such that any satisfiable sentence in L has a model of cardinality less or equal to $\mu$ if such exists. Otherwise, $\ell$(L)=$\infty$.

For a logic L and a quantifier $Q$, let L($Q$) be the logic L with $Q$ added to its language. Let $\mathcal{L}$ denote standard first order logic.

So, for instance: Let $Q_\alpha$ be the unary monadic quantifier ``there are at least $\aleph_\alpha$ many''. We have $\ell$($\mathcal{L}(Q_\alpha)$)=$\aleph_\alpha$ for each ordinal $\alpha$.

Another example: Let the Hartig quantifier $I$ be the binary monadic quantifier stating equal cardinality of sets: $I$ is a binary monadic quantifier such that $M\models Ix(\varphi x,\psi x)$ iff $|(\varphi x)^M|=|(\psi x)^M|$.
$\ell(\mathcal{L}(I))$ is very high, and is independent of ZFC. $\ell(\mathcal{L}(I))$ is a fixed point of the function $\alpha\mapsto\aleph_\alpha$, and further, Magidor and Vaananen showed that it is consistent with ZFC both that $\ell(\mathcal{L}(I))$ is under the first weakly inaccessible cardinal and that it is above the measurable cardinal ([Magidor and Vaananen, 2011](http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0219061311001018)).

Are there known results for "most" and "more"? I could only find the following bounds:

Let $Most$ be the binary monadic quantifier such that $M\models Most\ x (\varphi x, \psi x)$ iff $|(\varphi x)^M\backslash (\psi x)^M|<|(\varphi x)^M\cap(\psi x)^M|$. Then I've found the following lower bound: $\ell(\mathcal{L}(Most))\geq\aleph_\omega$.

Let $More$ be the binary monadic quantifier such that $M\models More\ x (\varphi x, \psi x)$ iff $|(\varphi x)^M|>|(\psi x)^M|$. Then we have both $\ell(\mathcal{L}(More))\geq\ell(\mathcal{L}(I))$ and $\ell(\mathcal{L}(More))\geq\ell(\mathcal{L}(Most))$ (due to considerations of expressive power).

Are there better results? And are there other quantifiers from ordinary language that have better results?

Comment: Posted also on [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/q/249239/98152).